# List multiple items on one condition line in process builder

Tags: process-builder, process, criteria

I want my criteria to run for users that are in quite a lot of roles in Salesforce.

Do I have to list each one-by-one? Tried to use commas and semi-colons but it will not work like that (e.g. like print-screen)

**EDIT: There are 13 roles to add but might need more!**

[image]

Comment: how many roles you want to add in your criteria?

Comment: @DhananjayPatil 13 for now but might need more - don't really want to add 13 condition rows - Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce doesn't support multiple values defined in process builder or flows. It is mentioned in the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214160&type=1)

> The Lightning Process Builder and Flow do not support comma-separated
>   values in rule criteria.

**Workaround**

> Using the same condition as above:
>
> Set Filter Conditions:
>
> ```
> 1) [Case].Contact.Email   CONTAINS   someone@company.com
> 2) [Case].Contact.Email   CONTAINS   someoneelse@company.com
> ```
>
> Filter Conditions (Customize the filter logic): (1 OR 2)

(P.S. I tried adding upto 38 conditions and it was going on and on. )

**Workaround #2**

You could also use the formula editor as well

```
OR([userrolefield] = 'Role1' ,
       [userrolefield] = 'Role2' ,
       [userrolefield] = 'Role3' ,
 ...
       [userrolefield] = 'Role-n' 
)
```

Comment: Tried to use Workaround#2 but when I add mt user role field and all the options I get 'The formula expression is invalid: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Text).' ERROR

Comment: Condition Criteria is Field: [user role field__c] Operator: Equals Type: Formula Value: (formula as per solution above)

Comment: I am not aware of the field names you have, since you have them concealed. Both workaround were presented to give you an idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the type to Formula and in the formula you can use the CASE() function like below:

CASE(fieldName,
"role1",  "role1",
"role2", "role2",
"role2", "role2",
"Not A Role")